# Error Line 1 unmet dependencies!

Tags: 14.04, apt, wine, java, error-handling

I got on today and after being on for 30 min it crashed and said there was a internal error. After restarting i had a red negative sign in the top right hand side of my menu bar. It said to look in my system files to find the error. I found this:

```
s# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted
```

Can some one help me fix this? I have no idea what caused or made this happen!

Comment: How did it say "to look in your system files"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `s` from the beginning of the line. Save the file, and run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: OMG! thank you so much the negative sign disappeared the second it updated!! Just curious how did this happen, and how can i prevent it for doing it again?

Comment: I have no idea how this happened. The only possibility I can think of is that you manually edited the file and accidentally entered an `s` in there.

Comment: Thank you, its just me being a noob not my laptop.. washoo!